# Could some common allergies be treated medicinally without antihistamins/steroids/epinephrine and if so how?

Tags: medications, allergy

A common allergy such as [house dust-mite allergy](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/dust-mites/symptoms-causes/syc-20352173) or a [food allergy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_allergy) can be treated with antihistamines, steroids and epinephrine.

I understand that there are [Mast cell stabilizers and Anti-leuko-trienes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allergy#Medication) as possible alternatives to antihistamines, steroids and epinephrine, but I might be wrong.

Could some common allergies be treated medicinally without antihistamins/steroids/epinephrine and if so how?

Comment: What is it about the wikipedia article you cite that doesn't lead you to believe mast cell stabilizers and antileukotrienes can be used as replacements in some cases? That's exactly what it says, and although it's wikipedia, the articles do cite authoritative references.

Comment: @CareyGregory nothing. I didn't read about if and how this is possible, I don't think I have the biochemistry knowledge to do that fruitfully.

Comment: Well, as written, the answer to your question is simply "yes." Perhaps rewording it to ask for a more detailed explanation would clarify that you're looking for more than just whether it's possible.

Comment: @CareyGregory I've tried to improve the question. It is possible that I have just done the opposite (making it worse) but, well, I've tried.

Comment: I think it's better. :)